# Need sample tiff image with CCITT Group 3 1D modified Huffman RLE encoded for testing

Tags: image, tiff, fax

I am doing some testing on decoding CCITT Group 3 1-dimensional TIFF images but couldn't find any samples online. It would be nice if anyone could provide or point me to somewhere I can actually find one.

Note: I am looking for G3 1-dimensional (TIFF compression type 2) not 2-dimensional TIFF images (TIFF compression type 3 with T4Options). All the acclaimed G3 1-dimensional tiffs are actually G3 2-dimensional images (TIFF compression type 3) which are not what I want.

Update: finally found [one](https://github.com/apache/commons-imaging/blob/master/src/test/data/images/tiff/3/1pagefax.tif) but it's a completely blank page and not ideal for testing.

Update 2: haven't found samples generated by other tools which conform to type 2 compression, so I am putting links here to the ones my own encoder generated in case someone else needs them.(I did test with my own encoder but the reason for this question is I want to test with third party samples to make sure I am doing it right). Anyway, here are the links [sample1](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/blob/master/images/g3_rle_longline.tif), [sample2](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/blob/master/images/g3_rle_makeup.tif) and [sample3](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/blob/master/images/g3_rle_no_makeup.tif).

Comment: I voted to close this issue, as it's about finding an off-site resource. Unfortunately, I don't know where it would be appropriate to ask... :-/ Anyway, I do have some [G3 1D TIFF samples](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/tree/master/imageio/imageio-tiff/src/test/resources/tiff/ccitt), all generated.

Comment: @haraldK thanks for your link. I did take a peak at the samples from the link but my decoder said it's compression type 3 not 2 and neither my decoder nor windows paint or any viewer windows has can open it.

Comment: The samples generated by my encoder open fine by all windows image viewer and the metadata is shown as T3 whereas compression type 3 will be shown as T4.

Comment: The samples I need are the so called CCITT Group 3 1D without EOL

Comment: Here are a few samples. I'm not sure if they have the EOL or not: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fJ9l8ful3uFPiOkZg2H8K9Q8zrZ8zqlX/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/117RPx9pcZb5W0cSGGF_43Rkc_b8gs0BH/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OLPmwjGi6V2xTuORoPBXcS5zl5To8yh4/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hyrunbz4xFOL5OPcCXhA9xYt4SzbQY3P/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j_nDjMAP1xKA-wjaAIR0QZeFJFbqILWP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @BitBank thanks. Unfortunately still compression type 3 and the first 3 ones crashed my decoder as it expects stripByteCounts which is missing from the image directory. My decoder is not lenient enough.

Comment: @BitBank I finally managed to decode and show two of the samples you provided. The other two failed. The failed ones are g3error.tif and g3crash.tif. They just show garbage for me. Note: other viewers I tested show them well. Do you happen to know or have the interest to take a look at what exactly makes the two failed ones different from the other working ones? many thanks!

Comment: Looks like the issue is in the fillOrder which is LSB2MSB. After taking that into account, I managed to decode g3error.tif successfully but for g3crash.tif the pixels are still a bit off.

Comment: Finally decoded all five of the images. Thanks again @BitBank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can finally close this question now. Thanks to HaraldK and BitBank for providing images for testing. Although the images are all for compression type 3 not 2, they are indeed one dimensional and they helped a lot in my testing with compression 3 1D decoding.